# How to create a bot in lex/azure that respond in slack threads?

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack-api, amazon-lex

I have created 2 chatbots using AWS lex and Azure bot framework each. I have integrated them with slack and they respond to the mentions in channels.

Currently, the bot responds as a new message however I want it to respond in the slack thread of the original message posted by the user. I tried to look for articles in various places but could not find anything helpful. Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this or a reference to a GitHub repo for a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to post replies, I am assuming that you are using `chat.postMessage` API.

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

To send the reply as a thread, all you need to do is that add `thread_ts` argument in the api call.
*(Provide original message's **ts** (timestamp) value to make this message a reply.)*